# MySQL defragment InnoDB tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb, mysqltuner

After running mysqltuner, I received this output:

```
Total fragmented tables: 284
```

To defragment I tried these:

```
1. ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENGINE=INNODB
2. Another way to perform a defragmentation operation is to use mysqldump to dump the table to a text file, drop the table, and reload it from the dump file.
```

Both of the methods are described in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html).

But none of the methods helped. Mysqltuner still says that tables are fragmented.

**Note:** `innodb_file_per_table` is OFF in my configurations.

How can I defragment my InnoDB tables?

Comment: Does running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on any of your tables help?

Comment: It returns "Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead"

Comment: I think Mysqltuner lies to you. `ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENGINE=INNODB` rebuilds the table, it can not be fragmented. You can use Jeremy's tool to explore InnoDB tablespace and check fragmentatopn level http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/03/a-quick-introduction-to-innodb-ruby/

Comment: I use the queries here https://www.deciusac.com/linux-2/how-to-optimize-mysql-tables-and-defragment-to-recover-space/ to see if it is still fragmented after optimizing it, and still I have the tables as fragmented

Comment: On which versions of MySQL does it work?

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENGINE=INNODB

Is  the only way to defragment a innodb table.

ALGORITHM=INPLACE can help us to do it online.

Answer (score 1):

> As of MySQL 5.5.11, you can also use **ALTER TABLE tbl_name FORCE**
>   to perform a “null” alter operation that *rebuilds the table*.
>   Previously the FORCE option was recognized but ignored.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the solution that worked for me was doing `analyze` after `alter`:

```
alter table xyz engine=InnoDB;
analyze table xyz;
```